# GoogleBigQuery How to exclude null values from a specific column in a union query?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I would like to filter out null values from a specific column in this case "Account" on a union query how can i do this?

The query that I am working on is this:

SELECT
Account,
Campaign_name,
Ad_group_name,
Date,
Keyword,
Impressions,
Clicks,
Cost__GBP_,
Conversions
FROM
`table1`
UNION ALL

SELECT
Account,
Campaign_name,
Ad_group_name,
Date,
Keyword,
Impressions,
Clicks,
Cost__GBP_,
Conversions
FROM
`table2`

Someone can help me in this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each query is evaluated separately in a union query.
So you should add WHERE filters to each of them.

```
SELECT Account, Campaign_name, Ad_group_name, Date, Keyword, Impressions, Clicks, Cost__GBP_, Conversions 
FROM table1 
WHERE Account is not NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT Account, Campaign_name, Ad_group_name, Date, Keyword, Impressions, Clicks, Cost__GBP_, Conversions 
FROM table2
WHERE Account is not NULL
```